# How can I refer to the "this" object in a Grails criteria query

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, criteria, grails-orm

I have a set of domain objects that are related like this:

```
class Book {
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}

class Contract {
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
    Book book
}

class Author {
     static hasMany = [books: Book, contracts: Contract]
}
```

I'd like to create a query that joins against all a book's author's contracts where the contract book is "this" book.  The question I want to answer is "what are all books under contract?"  Here what I have for the criteria, but I don't know how to refer to the "this" object:

```
Book.createCriteria().list() {
    author {
        contracts {
            eqProperty('book', '??') // what here??
        }
    }
}
```

Can I refer to the "this" object or somehow create an alias for it?

Comment: This might be of use as well http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/04/associations-and-criteria-queries.html

Answer (score 1):

did not write up a unit test, but I think you can do this..

[GORM Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html) Scroll down to eager fetching example to see example

```
Book.createCriteria().list() {
    author {
        contracts {
            eqProperty('book.id', book.id) // what here??
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Close, but that doesn't work the way I hoped.  `eqProperty` takes two property names.  I could use `eq` to find one specific book, but I'm trying to get it to join do a join between Book and Book.

Comment: @ataylor did you try just using 'eq' instead of 'eqProperty'

Comment: That didn't work either.  It isn't a specific book I want to find, rather I want to join against the book table.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @ataylor - Your question says you're trying to answer "is this book under contract?". Are you actually trying to answer "what are all of the books that are under contract"?

Comment: @Rob Hruska Yes, that's what I mean.  Good point, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Criteria builder, is straight HQL an option? I'm not the most fluent in HQL, but perhaps could you do something like:

```
// should return a collection of Books
Contract.executeQuery('select distinct c.book from Contract c')
```

If you need it to be for a specific Author, you can add a where clause accordingly ([docs](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html)).

Comment: That's a possibility, but I haven't figured out how to [chain HQL queries together](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) like criteria queries, and I really like that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a version of grails running on this machine I was unable to test this for syntax.

You may be able to do something like this:
add "import org.hibernate.FetchMode as FM" to your Controller or Service

```
Contract.withCriteria{
    createAlias('book','b')
    fetchMode('book',FM.EAGER)
}.book.unique()
```